# Como utilizar o Qhull

Tags: c++, qhull

Vocês conhecem o *Qhull*? Ele faz uma triangulação *delaunay*.

Eu tenho um conjunto de pontos em uma arquivo e estou querendo gerar os vértices, mas não estou conseguindo colocar os comandos no programa.

Comment: Poste o que você fez até o momento para podermos ajudar. Coloque também o erro obtido, e o que era esperado.

Comment: O problema é interessante, mas precisa contextualizar melhor a questão. Sugestão de leitura para um melhor aproveitamento do site: **[Tour]** e **[ask]**. Depois, basta um clique no link **[edit]** embaixo da pergunta original, para acrescentar os detalhes relevantes.